# Is it possible to create a code snippet to create code elsewhere in the file?

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

I'm trying to create a code snippet which will check a variable for null and create a private variable for it.

Currently I have:

```
<Code Language="csharp">
  <![CDATA[if ($arg$ == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("$arg$");
      _$arg$ = $arg$;$end$]]>
</Code>
```

If I use this on a variable called `value` it will create

```
_value = value;
```

However I want to create `_value`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

short answer (to my knwoledge): no.

long answer: maybe you can create a snippet that defines the variable and the function stub that uses this null-check, that would fit sequentially into the snippet ;)